# Get most recent message sent to user per user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to sort my messages from users in the same way twitter handles it. So each user who has sent a message to me should be listed and with their latest message to me below.

My query to try and get this seems like it should work to me but it doesn't. It returns the first message the user sent to me so the opposite.

This is my query:

```
$messages = Message::with('user')->where('target_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->latest()->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

The Message table looks like this:

```
id
message
user_id ( user sending the message id)
target_user_id ( user the message is sent to id)
```

I have tried the method people directed my to as duplicate without success. I get the same results and with my current query.

This is what i tried:

```
$messages = Message::with('user')->where('target_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->select(DB::raw('t.*'))
->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY created_at DESC) t'))
->groupBy('t.user_id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `distinct` and `orderBy` and check if works for your problem:

```
$messages = Message::with('user')
                   ->where('target_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                   ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                   ->distinct('user_id')
                   ->get();
```

Comment: I think distinct user_id is what you want.

Comment: You are right, @Devon. Thanks!

Comment: @Laerte Tried this, i don't think distinct really does what i need. This still returns multiple messages from same user. I wont to only show 1 message from each user and it should be the latest message.